# ¿Cómo crear archivo Excel desde código C# con atributos de lectura y escritura?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel

Creo un nuevo archivo Excel desde código C#, pero cuando lo abro me dice que es solo de lectura por que el archivo aun está en uso.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que sea de lectura y escritura?

Código:

```
   public bool CreateFileXlsx (List<Person> persons , string pathFile,IEngineTool Tool)
        {
            bool resultado = false;

            Excel.Application excel = default(Excel.Application);       
            Excel.Workbook libro = default(Excel.Workbook);
            Excel.Worksheet hoja = default(Excel.Worksheet);
            excel = new Excel.Application();
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            try
            {
                libro = excel.Workbooks.Add();
                hoja = libro.Worksheets[1];
                hoja.Activate();

                hoja.Range["A1"].Value = "FOTO";
                hoja.Range["B1"].Value = "NOMBRE";
                hoja.Range["C1"].Value = "APELLIDO";
                hoja.Range["D1"].Value = "DNI";
                hoja.Range["E1"].Value = "MATRICULA";
                hoja.Range["F1"].Value = "RH";
                hoja.Range["G1"].Value = "GRADO";
                hoja.Range["H1"].Value = "GRUPO";
                hoja.Range["I1"].Value = "EMAIL";
                hoja.Range["J1"].Value = "EMPRESA";
                hoja.Range["K1"].Value = "QR";
                hoja.Range["L1"].Value = "FOTO64";
                hoja.Range["M1"].Value = "QR64";

                int n = 2;
                string foto64 = string.Empty;
                string sourceQr = string.Empty;
                string qr64 = string.Empty;
                foreach (Person p in persons)
                {
                    foto64 = Tool.ConvertImgTo64Img(p.Foto);
                    sourceQr = p.Nombre + p.Apellido + p.Dni;
                    sourceQr = Tool.ConvertirBase64(sourceQr);
                    p.Qr = Tool.CreateQrCode(sourceQr, @"C:\QR_ARCHIVOS\" + Valor.NombreEmpresa + "\\" + Valor.NombreEmpresa + "_QR\\" + p.Dni + ".png");
                     qr64 = Tool.ConvertImgTo64Img(@"C:\QR_ARCHIVOS\" + Valor.NombreEmpresa + "\\" + Valor.NombreEmpresa + "_QR\\" + p.Dni + ".png");

                    hoja.Range["A" + n].Value = p.Foto;
                    hoja.Range["B" + n].Value = p.Nombre;
                    hoja.Range["C" + n].Value = p.Apellido;
                    hoja.Range["D" + n].Value = p.Dni;
                    hoja.Range["E" + n].Value = p.Matricula;
                    hoja.Range["F" + n].Value = p.Rh;
                    hoja.Range["G" + n].Value = p.Grado;
                    hoja.Range["H" + n].Value = p.Grupo;
                    hoja.Range["I" + n].Value = p.Email;
                    hoja.Range["J" + n].Value = p.Company;
                    hoja.Range["K" + n].Value = p.Qr;
                    hoja.Range["L" + n].Value = foto64;
                    hoja.Range["M" + n].Value = qr64;
                    n++;
                }
                excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100;
                excel.Columns.AutoFit();
                excel.Rows.AutoFit();
                libro.SaveAs(pathFile);

                resultado = true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error:  " + ex.ToString());
            }

            return resultado;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el archivo es de lectura/escritura, lo que ocurre es que tu proceso no lo libera, y por eso cuando lo abres desde Excel te dice que está en uso.

Para liberarlo tras guardar puedes probar a meter el código en un bloque `using`, (si implementa IDisposable, cosa que ahora mismo ignoro), algo así:

```
using(Excel.Apllication Excel = new Excel.Application()){
… Tu código
}
```

O bien tratando de liberar las referencias manualmente:

```
excel.Quit();//y lo que sea para el resto
```